# Ubuntu 22.04 Software Center Prompt For Wrong User's Password

Tags: 22.04, software-center

We have a number of workstations where users authenticate through LDAP. An LDAP user has sudo privileges on their workstation via local group assignment to sudo as well as through IPA Sudo Policy rules, and can use cli tools (e.g. sudo apt, sudo apt-get, etc.) with no problems. But when they want to install something through the (GUI) Software Center, they are prompted for a different user's credentials, not their own. It seems logical that if a user with sudo on the machine is the active user, their credentials would be needed to install software, not someone else's. Is this a bug and/or is there a way to change it?